# Problems outsourcing RSA encryption and decryption

Tags: android, encryption, rsa

i have a problem with RSA encryption and decryption. I'm developing in android and would like to outsource the RSA encryption and decryption. My source code worked well before i tried to outsource it.

I created a private key and public key and saved it as private.key and public.key. The error is a ClassNotFoundException caused by this method:

```
public Key getPrivateKey(){
  try {
    InputStream fis = activity.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.private);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    Key RSAprivateKey = (Key)ois.readObject();
    return RSAprivateKey;
  }
  catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    Log.e("FileNotFound","FileNotFound");
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("IOEXception","IOEXception");
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    Log.e("ClassNotFound","ClassNotFound");
    Log.e("Errro", "Error: "+ e.getMessage());
    Log.e("error", e.toString());
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return null;
}
```

I looked at the logcat and got this error message:

```
E/ClassNotFound(1205): ClassNotFound
03-19 13:54:52.176: E/Errro(1205): Error: 
com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JCERSAPrivateCrtKey
03-19 13:54:52.176: E/error(1205): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JCERSAPrivateCrtKey
```

I hope you understand my problem, because English is not my native language.

Edit: I found out that the problem is not caused by outsourcing the code. So i guess the topic can be marked as solved.

Comment: FYI - your logging is very weird. You probably just want one `catch (Exception e)` statement containing `Log.e(TAG, "Error loading key", e);`, where `TAG` is a static string defined elsewhere, e.g. `private static final String TAG = MyActivity.class.getName();`.

Comment: Please edit your question with the comments you added to my now-deleted answer. Maybe someone can help you.

Comment: There is no such thing as "marking it as solved". You can however delete the question if it won't be if help to anyone else.

Comment: I solved it. I genereted a new key and loaded it from raw folder as an inputstream. Then i used the classes PKCS8EncodedKeySpec and X509EncodedKeySpec to generate The keys.

Comment: Post your answer so this can be closed.

Comment: You are able to post an answer to to your own question and then accept it. Providing sufficient detail in your answer can help other people who face a similar problem and find this question through a search engine.

Comment: I think you meant "obfuscate," not "outsource."

Answer (score 1):

`RSAPublicKey` and `RSAPrivateKey` are interfaces. When you get a `Key` you actually receive an implementation by the cryptographic provider of this interface. These providers differ for different Java platforms (although, at least officially, Android/Dalvik isn't even a Java platform). So you should never expect serialization to work unless you are working on the same platform.

There are however ways to serialize public and private keys in Java; the `Key` interface contains the `getEncoded()` method which returns the most common binary encoding of the key. In the case of `RSAPublicKey` this is the PKCS#1 encoding within X5.09 SubjectKeyIdentifier. In the case of `RSAPrivateKey` this is the *inner* PKCS#8 encoding wrapped around the PKCS#1 defined structure. These can be represented using `X509EncodedKeySpec` and `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec` and converted back into keys using an RSA `KeyFactory`.

Note that the private key *will not* be encrypted if you call `getEncoded`. Normally you don't want to transport private keys *at all*, and if you do you should really encrypt them. You can do this using the `Cipher.wrap` and `Cipher.unwrap` methods.